# How do I implement a tree table view in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, controls, treetable

Any idea how I can implement a tree table view in cocoa like  [cocoacookies](http://ditchnet.org/cocoacookies/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NSOutlineView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you want to use bindings, use [`NSTreeController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as well.

You’ll probably want to read the [Outline View Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html) document.

Comment: Hi, can you give some example about cocoa binding with NSTreeController, without using core data ? Thanks. I googled it for a while but find the most of examples (like SourceView) are kinda overwhelmed :$

Comment: @Qiulang Not really. SourceView was the example I used to learn it.

Comment: For starters, why SourceView did not use NSTreeNode ? And when I read "core data" (the pragmatic book), it said "Unfortunately, there is still quite a bit of work to be done with the NSTreeController, and the results we get from working with it can be unexpected and unclear. Therefore, I recommend skipping it at this time and implementing the data source protocol instead when working with tree data."  I googled NStreeController for while and it seems that many people complained that NStreeController was buggy too.